# Thread confusion in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

This code doesn't print the main thread at all. All it does is print the child thread. But if i make one change, i.e bring the statement "r.t.start()" out of this try block and put it in a try block of its own. So, when i do that, the threads work like they're supposed to. Why does that happen?

```
public class prctc2 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        NewThread r = new NewThread();
        try {
            r.t.start();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + i);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }

}

class NewThread implements Runnable {
    Thread t;

    NewThread() {
        t = new Thread(this, "new one");
    }

    public void run() {

        try {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                System.out.println(t + " " + i);
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }

        }

        catch (Exception e) {}
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't be suppressing all your exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer: but I made some changes in your program to make it look more professional:

Changed `prctc2` to `Prctc2`.  Class names should always be capitalized.

I took the `Thread t` member out of the `NewThread` class.  A class should always be responsible for just one thing:  Yours was responsible for two:  It's first responsibility was to print out the numbers from 1 to 5, and its second responsibility was to start the thread.

I moved the `.start()` call into `main()` which (IMO) makes the code easier to understand.

I renamed `NewThread` to `MyTask`.  It is *not* a Thread, and because of my change above, it no longer even *has* a thread, so "thread" should not appear in its name.

I changed the exception handlers to print the stack traces.  One of the worst things you can do is ignore exceptions.  That can make it hard to debug your program if it does anything that you didn't expect it to do.

```
public class Prctc2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Thread r = new Thread(new MyTask());
        r.start();

        try {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + i);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class MyTask implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        try {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                System.out.println(t + " " + i);
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```